# Crystal report crash on page setup settings

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

Report is created in visual studio 2010 and have installed SAP crystal report, version for visual studio 2010 v13.0.3 and SAP crystal report runtime engine for .NET framework(64-bit).
I've crystal report 13.0.2000 that I'm having problem with. When I open a report and change the page setup settings like margins,orientation, etc and try to save it, it crashes, saying program stopped working.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Report is created in visual studio 2010 and have installed SAP crystal report, version for visual studio 2010 v13.0.3 and SAP crystal report runtime engine for .NET framework(64-bit). I've crystal report 13.0.2000 that I'm having problem with. When I open a report and change the page setup settings like margins,orientation, etc and try to save it, it crashes, saying program stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to remove all printers in my computer. This issue comes when printer driver is corrupted.